# Why doesn't it return an HttpResponse even though render returns?

Tags: python, django, web

My html template and urlpatterns are checked OK, but it just doesn't response anything and saying like this `The view search.views.search_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` So what's wrong?

If I return HttpResponse('hello world'), it still just tell me returning nothing?

```py
def search_list(request):
    #return render(request, '/', locals())

    start_time = time.time()
    searched = True
    keywords = request.GET.get('q')
    print(keywords)
    message = ''
    if not keywords:
        return redirect('/')
    #words = keywords.split('')
    word = keywords
    post_list = Poem.objects.filter(Q(author_name__contains=word) | Q(model_name__contains=word) | Q(poem_name__contains=word) | Q(dynasty__contains=word) | Q(content__contains=word))
    print(post_list)
    try:
        old_word = SearchHotspot.object.get(word=word)
    except:
        new_word = SearchHotspot()
        new_word.word = word
        new_word.count += 1
        new_word.save()
    else:
        old_word.count += 1
        old_word.save()
    limit = 10
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, limit)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    end_time = time.time()
    load_time = end_time - start_time

    title = keywords + "- 众里寻他千百度"
    content = "蓦然回首，那人却在灯火阑珊处。"

    return render(request, 'search/result.html', locals())
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`?

Comment: thanks, the question has been solved; I have redefined another search_list function but uncompletely

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is your request, but if you get into the if statement "if not keyword", you state "return redirect", which would cause this error. The correct method is [HttpReponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses)

Comment: redirect is a django shortcut that returns an HttpResponseRedirect object, shouldn't it work even if the it falls into 'if not keyword'?

Comment: thanks, the question has been solved; I have redefined another search_list function but uncompletely

Comment: oh yeah! he would need to import from django.shorcuts but HttpResponseRedirect would need too, you're right, not very useful